# Erro query SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Possuo o seguinte SQL:

```
INSERT INTO SISCli (CdInscricao,DsEntidade,DsApelido,InInscricao,InCadastro,DsEndereco,NrCEP,NrInscricaoEstadual,NrCGCCPF,NrTelefone,DtCadastro,CdEmpresa,DsEMail,DsUSuarioInc,InClassificacaoFiscal,DsBairro)
SELECT
    case when LEN(ESP353_XML.DES_NrCGCCPF)=13 then '0'+ CAST(ESP353_XML.DES_NrCGCCPF AS VARCHAR)
         when LEN(ESP353_XML.DES_NrCGCCPF)=12 then '00'+ CAST(ESP353_XML.DES_NrCGCCPF AS VARCHAR)
         when LEN(ESP353_XML.DES_NrCGCCPF)=11 then '000'+ CAST(ESP353_XML.DES_NrCGCCPF AS VARCHAR)
         when LEN(ESP353_XML.DES_NrCGCCPF)=10 then '0000'+ CAST(ESP353_XML.DES_NrCGCCPF AS varchar)
         when LEN(ESP353_XML.DES_NrCGCCPF)=9  then '00000'+ CAST(ESP353_XML.DES_NrCGCCPF AS varchar)
         when LEN(ESP353_XML.DES_NrCGCCPF)=8  then '000000'+ CAST(ESP353_XML.DES_NrCGCCPF AS varchar)
         when LEN(ESP353_XML.DES_NrCGCCPF)=7  then '0000000'+ CAST(ESP353_XML.DES_NrCGCCPF AS varchar)
         when LEN(ESP353_XML.DES_NrCGCCPF)=6  then '00000000'+ CAST(ESP353_XML.DES_NrCGCCPF AS varchar)
         else CAST(ESP353_XML.DES_NrCGCCPF AS varchar)
    end AS [CdInscricao],
    ESP353_XML.DES_DsEntidade AS [DsEntidade],
    ESP353_XML.DES_DsApelido AS [DsApelido],
    case when LEN(ESP353_XML.DES_NrCGCCPF)>11 then 0 else 1 end AS [InInscricao],
    0 AS [InCadastro],
    ESP353_XML.DES_DsEndereco AS [DsEndereco],
    ESP353_XML.DES_NrCEP AS [NrCEP],
    'ISENTO' AS [NrInscricaoEstadual],
    case when LEN(ESP353_XML.DES_NrCGCCPF)=13 then '0'+ CAST(ESP353_XML.DES_NrCGCCPF AS VARCHAR)
         when LEN(ESP353_XML.DES_NrCGCCPF)=12 then '00'+ CAST(ESP353_XML.DES_NrCGCCPF AS VARCHAR)
         when LEN(ESP353_XML.DES_NrCGCCPF)=11 then ''+ CAST(ESP353_XML.DES_NrCGCCPF AS VARCHAR)
         when LEN(ESP353_XML.DES_NrCGCCPF)=10 then '0'+ CAST(ESP353_XML.DES_NrCGCCPF AS varchar)
         when LEN(ESP353_XML.DES_NrCGCCPF)=9  then '00'+ CAST(ESP353_XML.DES_NrCGCCPF AS varchar)
         when LEN(ESP353_XML.DES_NrCGCCPF)=8  then '000'+ CAST(ESP353_XML.DES_NrCGCCPF AS varchar)
         when LEN(ESP353_XML.DES_NrCGCCPF)=7  then '0000'+ CAST(ESP353_XML.DES_NrCGCCPF AS varchar)
         when LEN(ESP353_XML.DES_NrCGCCPF)=6  then '00000'+ CAST(ESP353_XML.DES_NrCGCCPF AS varchar)
         else CAST(ESP353_XML.DES_NrCGCCPF AS varchar)
    end AS [NrCGCCPF],
    ESP353_XML.DES_NrTelefone AS [NrTelefone],
    GETDATE() AS [DtCadastro],
    1 as [CdEmpresa],
    'a@a.com' as [DsEMail],
    'EdiXMLMI' AS [DsUSuarioInc],
    7 AS [InClassificacaoFiscal],
    substring(ISNULL(ESP353_XML.DES_DsBairro,0),1,15) as [DES_DsBairro]
FROM ESP353_XML
where NOT exists (select 1 from SISCli A WHERE cast(A.CdInscricao as numeric) = cast(ESP353_XML.DES_NrCGCCPF as numeric))
```

Ao executa-lo retorna o erro abaixo:

```
Mensagem 512, Nível 16, Estado 1, Procedimento TRG_BloqueioInsereRegInvalido, Linha 7
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Porém se eu colocar um top 1 após o `SELECT` e ir executando um por um funciona.

Até agora não descobri o erro que retorna abaixo e o por que.

Comment: Observação: ao invés de fazer esse case when gigante pra formatar o seu campo, faça assim: 
`right('0000000000000' + CAST(ESP353_XML.DES_NrCGCCPF AS varchar),'13')`

Comment: veja se lhe ajuda: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33654508/insert-with-select-causes-subquery-returned-more-than-1-value-eventhough-subqu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Porém se eu colocar um top 1 após o SELECT e ir executando um por um funciona.*

O erro não está no código de inclusão mas sim no procedimento de gatilho TRG_BloqueioInsereRegInvalido. Como o código de inclusão funciona quando se inclui uma linha de cada vez, provavelmente o procedimento TRG_BloqueioInsereRegInvalido está programado de forma incorreta, preparado para receber somente uma linha a cada execução.  Como consta em [Estudo de casos de tópicos relacionados a procedimentos trigger](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/pt-br/contents/articles/37857.t-sql-estudo-de-casos-de-topicos-do-forum-technet-relacionados-a-procedimentos-trigger.aspx), “*Esse é o erro mais comum na programação de procedimentos trigger, em T-SQL: programar o procedimento como se a cada chamada do procedimento fosse recebida uma única linha nas tabelas virtuais*”.

Um procedimento trigger em T-SQL deve ser programado considerando-se que as tabelas virtuais INSERTED e DELETED podem ter nenhuma, uma ou mais linhas. Caso tenha dificuldades em reprogramar o procedimento TRG_BloqueioInsereRegInvalido, sugiro que abra outro tópico com informações sobre o procedimento.

Sugestão adicional de leitura: [Armadilhas na programação de procedimentos de gatilho](https://portosql.wordpress.com/2018/08/18/armadilhas-na-programacao-de-trigger/).

---

Você pode simplificar o código de inclusão. Avalie a sugestão abaixo.

```
-- código #1
INSERT INTO SISCli (CdInscricao, DsEntidade, DsApelido, InInscricao, InCadastro, DsEndereco, NrCEP, NrInscricaoEstadual, NrCGCCPF, NrTelefone, DtCadastro, CdEmpresa, DsEMail, DsUSuarioInc, InClassificacaoFiscal, DsBairro)
     SELECT right( ('00000000' + cast(ESP353_XML.DES_NrCGCCPF as varchar)), 14) as [CdInscricao],
            ESP353_XML.DES_DsEntidade AS [DsEntidade],
            ESP353_XML.DES_DsApelido AS [DsApelido],
            case when LEN(ESP353_XML.DES_NrCGCCPF) > 11 then 0 else 1 end AS [InInscricao],
            0 AS [InCadastro],
            ESP353_XML.DES_DsEndereco AS [DsEndereco],
            ESP353_XML.DES_NrCEP AS [NrCEP],
            'ISENTO' AS [NrInscricaoEstadual],
            case when LEN(ESP353_XML.DES_NrCGCCPF) > 11
                 then right( ('00'+ cast(ESP353_XML.DES_NrCGCCPF as varchar)), 14) 
                 else right( ('00000'+ cast(ESP353_XML.DES_NrCGCCPF as varchar)), 11) end as [NrCGCCPF],
            ESP353_XML.DES_NrTelefone AS [NrTelefone],
            current_timestamp AS [DtCadastro],
            1 as [CdEmpresa],
            'a@a.com' as [DsEMail],
            'EdiXMLMI' AS [DsUSuarioInc],
            7 AS [InClassificacaoFiscal],
            substring(ISNULL(ESP353_XML.DES_DsBairro,0),1,15) as [DES_DsBairro]
       from ESP353_XML
       where not exists (select * from SISCli as A 
                         where cast(A.CdInscricao as numeric) = cast(ESP353_XML.DES_NrCGCCPF as numeric));
```

---

Comment: Simplificando deste jeito aumenta a performance ? Ou simplesmente diminui o código ?

Comment: @Kevin.F: A sugestão do código #1 foi com o objetivo de tornar o código _limpo_. Inclusive facilita a compreensão e a manutenção por terceiros. // Para otimizar o código #1 sugiro que pesquise na Wikipedia por `sargable`, pois o SELECT dentro da função EXISTS() pode estar causando varredura completa na tabela SISCli.

Comment: Não entendi muito bem este termo `sargable`. Então o erro acima da query seria na trigger da tabela que estou tentando inserir os dados correto ?

Comment: @Kevin.F: Segundo a mensagem de erro que você postou, o erro ocorreu no procedimento trigger `TRG_BloqueioInsereRegInvalido`. Os artigos da série "Armadilhas na programação de procedimentos de gatilho" detalham causas e possíveis soluções.